# What does F(a)(b) mean in the context of extension fields?

Tags: abstract-algebra, notation

I understand that F(a) is the smallest subfield that contains both F and a.  What is the definition of F(a)(b)?  I'm supposed to prove that it's equal to F(a,b), but without knowing how F(a)(b) is defined, I'm at a loss where to begin.

Comment: The smallest field containing F(a) and b. It might help to set L=F(a) so that F(a)(b) = L(b) is the smallest field containing L and b, which is the smallest field containing F(a) and b.

Answer (score 4):

Let $K=F(a)$. Then $F(a)(b)=K(b)$. A slightly clearer notation might be $(F(a))(b)$ but some authors despise parenthesis overload.

Comment: I would agree with those authors, that is not clearer.

Comment: I think the parentheses would have helped me.  Thanks, all.

Comment: Luckily, as $F(a)(b)=F(a,b)$, after this exercise we don't need to use multiple parenthesis in this context.